# No Ouput when creating Cloudformation stack with an Outputs section

Tags: json, aws-cloudformation

When Creating a stack with an S3 bucket, When I create this stack I do not get an output from Cloudformation. What am I missing?

```
{                 
    "Resources" : {
        "S3BKT" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket",
            "DeletionPolicy" : "Retain",
            "Properties" : {
                "AccessControl" : "PublicRead",
                "WebsiteConfiguration" : {
                    "IndexDocument" : "index.html",
                    "ErrorDocument" : "error.html"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs" : {
        "WebsiteURL" : {
            "Value" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "S3BKT", "WebsiteURL" ] },
            "Description" : "URL for website hosted on S3"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the template. You issue must originate from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

uploaded this template and got a error:

**does not support attribute type Access Control in Fn::GetAtt**

Removed **PublicRead** and replaced with **PublicReadWrite** and I got an output. Re-ran the template with **PublicRead** again and got an output.

Super weird. but it worked. Thanks Marcin for your response!